# Updating .net core sdk version to 1.0.3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am create project in **Visual Studio 2015** with the sdk version **"1.0.0-preview2-003131"**. Now I need to update it to **1.0.3**. I downloaded **1.0.3** SDK version and change it in **global.json.**

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test", "SiteMapGen" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Then these 2 errors [appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGJ0.jpg):

[image: The errors]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Read [ask], include the errors and your research in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any SDK from RC3 (Could be RC4, not 100%, but around there) onwards is only compatible with Visual Studio 2017. Essentially if the tutorial you are reading is using a csproj file and not a project.json file, then you need to use Visual Studio 2017.

.net core csproj files cannot be opened using Visual Studio 2015. project.json .net core projects cannot be opened using Visual Studio 2017. If you are working on an existing project then you need to migrate that project to the latest .net core tooling and use Visual Studio 2017 to work on it.

Now you can actually develop on two different versions of the SDK side by side (More info here : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/02/17/developing-two-versions-net-core-sdk-side-side/). global.json is how you control it so you have that part right.